# it replaces a text input when multiple letter buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle application below:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/3/)

If you open the jsfiddle, you will see a top control which contains "Answer" buttons. You will also see some letter buttons, a "True" button, and a "False" button.

The "True" and "False" buttons work perfectly, meaning that if the user clicks on "True" and then clicks on "False", it replaces the text input as you can't have an answer both "True" and "False".

But there is a problem with the letter buttons. If you click on the letter buttons, you realise that you can click on multiple letter buttons which is fine, but the problem is that it replaces the text input for those letters which is incorrect. If multiple letter buttons are selected, then it should display the text inputs for all of those letter buttons, not replace the text input with the latest letter button selected.

So does anyone know what I need to change in the code in order to achieve this?

Comment: This is homework, isn't it? You're linking us to your project on a school server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate an `data-hid` for the button here:

```
var hid = "hidden" + id + n + "value";  
$(btn).attr("data-hid", hid);
```

based on this you now generate an input field:

```
var input = '<input type="text" id="' + hid + '" value="' + value + '" name="' + id + 'value" />';
```

The id variable in this is the id of the button, which will be `answerC` for example. So with this you will get an hid of `#hiddenanswerC0value` when you first click the button.

However when you add an answer the buttons will have an id generated like this:

```
.attr('id', $this.attr('id')+'Row');
```

So it will have an extra `Row` at the end. So the `data-hid` and the input box will be different as well (`#hiddenanswerCRow0value`).

**Edit:**
Another problem is that you don't actually create the data-hid for the new buttons. You only create it for the first set of buttons after clicking on them. But when you create the second set (after clicking) with the C button already activated it will not have the `data-hid` set and therefore you cannot delete it.

Comment: Let me just change the fiddle, I think I am able to generate a count for each answer belonging to each question but I have a different problem

Comment: I have updated question and updated fiddle, can you please try and solve this problem instead?

Comment: Is that the problem you are referring to in the updated fiddle I posted?

Comment: No. it refers to the first fiddle. If you have another problem with the code which is not related, please open another question. Changing the question completely will confuse people, because the answers don't match the question anymore (like now). Also you cannot expect people to do your homework step for step. Try to do it yourself and if you have a specific problem, ask a specific question about the code. Then continue and if you have another problem, open another one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like the input ID is getting set properly on that first one you're having problems with.  I show it gets an ID of "#hiddenanswerC0value" but should be "#hiddenanswerCRow0value", if I'm not mistaken.  I'll look into it a bit more, but that might be enough for you to figure it out.

Comment: I will update qustion because I have changed the fiddle and I have a different problem, forget the original problem

Comment: I have updated question and updated fiddle, can you please try and solve this problem instead?